# Remove noisy log messages like AcceptBlockHeader

Tags: logging

is there a way to suppress outputting those kind of logs?

```
2019-11-07T00:32:02Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: prev block not found
2019-11-07T01:02:36Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: Consensus::ContextualCheckBlockHeader: 000000000000014219120d5167a4281437fc379129d4ba6f6e956ca1db77f5fa, bad-diffbits, incorrect proof of work
2019-11-07T01:08:55Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: Consensus::ContextualCheckBlockHeader: 000000004bfb561102f5f04d4bab0cc70a403da70b82ce33657e10ed46b9000f, bad-diffbits, incorrect proof of work
2019-11-07T04:16:24Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: Consensus::ContextualCheckBlockHeader: 000000000000001daed8bac77bdf571441649e51732e91bec984cf97a39005a1, bad-diffbits, incorrect proof of work
2019-11-07T04:22:01Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: Consensus::CheckBlockHeader: 0fd7ab36246daf61802e10a0316cc2b0f17a1d6404bfdd53878ba34e158b4680, high-hash, proof of work failed
2019-11-07T10:12:22Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: Consensus::CheckBlockHeader: 0fd7ab36246daf61802e10a0316cc2b0f17a1d6404bfdd53878ba34e158b4680, high-hash, proof of work failed
2019-11-07T23:10:53Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: prev block not found
```

They are kind of noisy and I would like to drop them from my log.
I saw that there was an issue opened in 2019 but it doesn't seem to have been pursued:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/17421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, `ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: Consensus::CheckBlockHeader:` can be excluded from log file using `-debug` or `-debugexclude` mentioned in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/10123/ because it is assigned a category 'VALIDATION' in: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/48c1083632687a42ac603d4f241e70616a1d3815/src/validation.cpp#L3643

Other error messages saved in logs are not assigned any [category](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/48c1083632687a42ac603d4f241e70616a1d3815/src/logging.cpp#L132) and `LogPrintf` is used instead of `LogPrint` in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/48c1083632687a42ac603d4f241e70616a1d3815/src/validation.cpp#L3622

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your explanation and help. I will try it out.